# Convert cURL request to Guzzle in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I have a curl request like the following in Codeigniter :

```
$order = [
  'index' => 'Value',
  'index2' => 'Value2'
];

$this->curl->create($this->base_url.'order/');
$this->curl->http_login($creds['username'], $creds['password']);
$this->curl->ssl(TRUE, 2, 'certificates/certificate.pem');
$this->curl->option(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
$this->curl->option(CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE);

$this->curl->post(json_encode($order));
$data   = $this->curl->execute();
```

Now I need to issue same request in Laravel, where I am using Guzzle. How can I convert this to a Guzzle request  ?

Answer (score 0):

Very, very easy:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $this->base_url]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'order/', [
  'form_params' => $order,
  'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  ],
  'auth' => [$creds['username'], $creds['password']],
  'http_errors' => false,
  'verify' => 'certificates/certificate.pem'
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

Note that this has nothing to do with Laravel, it's just Guzzle. Laravel doesn't affect Guzzle API in any way.

Comment: So what about the SSL and certificate ?

Comment: @HappyCoder Guzzle supports SSL requests by default, I assume your base_url() returns a string starting with https://

Comment: @HappyCoder but if you are using a self-signed certificate, you can just add 'verify' => 'certificates/certificate.pem' or 'verify' => false to disable SSL cert checks

Comment: There is another issue here that is with Auth. The API is using basic http auth, but it is returning error Authorization Required. The username and password are correct as I am getting response when used in Postman client.

Comment: @HappyCoder for basic auth, simply remove last item from the array ('digest')